# How to change font-family of all items of asp dropdownlist?

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a basic asp dropdownlist. how can i change the font of all option in dropdownlist? IF i add a cssclass in ddl , the selected item's font only change but remaining item's font dont change??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect the element in Chrome (F12), see what is the default style applied? if no styles then do like this

```
.select { /* style your select */
    font-family: 'Courier New';
}
.select option { /* style your options */
    font-family: 'Elephant';
}
```

Comment: This is not working in firefox but chrome<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPensionType" DataSourceID="dsdPensionType"   
                                           DataTextField="PENSION_TYPE_NAME_B" DataValueField="PENSION_TYPE_ID" Width="200px" runat="server">                                                
                                            </asp:DropDownList>

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. use below CSS:

```
 option{
            
            font-family://your font here//;                
            
        }
```

Remember this  solution works in Chrome. For Firefox I haven't found any one otherwise your font would be in Windows\Fonts directory.